# spring framework download

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, installation, unzip

So i downloaded Spring Jars from this [link](http://www.springsource.com/download/community)  and I am trying to unzip the file, it keeps on complaining that some of the total path and file must not exceed 260 chars and it breaks from unzipping. How to download the jars and include them in my eclipse installation for working on my web projects, although this may seem trivial for some people it is very annoying to get around as i am new this kind of stuff. Really appreciate your help.

Thanks,
SS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you just unzip the zip file or the jar files? Just unzip the zip file, copy the jars in a lib folder in your project and add the jars to the buildpath of your project (Right click on the project -> Properties -> Java Build path -> Libraries -> Add jars).

And don't use the unzip functionality included in Windows, use an external program like 7zip. Then that error shouldn't occur.

Comment: Yes i am on windows 7 and I right click on the zip file and trying to unzip it , it stops half way with the error message "Total path and file name length must not exceed 260 chars"

Comment: Sweet 7zip worked perfectly fine, I was using winrar also, which gave me error. Thank you very much.

Comment: +1 - Just did it successfully on my Windows machine; I used WinZip to extract the files.  No problem.

Comment: As i said you have to use a separate unzip tool. Windows per default does not allow path names with more than 255 characters, and the source code of the spring framework, which is included in the zip, has a deeper directory structure.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to unzip or unjar JAR files to use them in Eclipse.  In fact, I'd recommend NOT doing this ... especially on Windows ... because it is liable to increase the amount of disk I/O.

But if you do want / need to do this, the `jar` command that is part of a Java JDK installation will be able to cope with them.

Answer (score 1):

What you got was the correct ZIP . Now try to unzip it in something like **c:\Spring** instead of a nested folder like **C:\Users\abcuser\Downloads\Spring\Spring Framework** Notice the size difference between file paths.

To add jars to your eclipse project -

1. Right click project
2. Click "Build path" -> Configure Build Path... -> Libraries Tab
3. Click add external jar and select your jar

Comment: That was very stupid of me not to think of such thing, I guess it is because i work on spring development only when i am drunk and I loose my normal thinking ability and get in to super thinking ability... :)